# Washing After Leaving Cemetary

Tags: sources-mekorot, rambam, netilat-yadayim-washing, cemetery-grave

What are the earliest sources (i.e. Chazal or Rishonim) for washing one's hands after visiting a cemetery?

Is this mentioned by the Rambam?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **Geonic responsum** (T'shuvos HaGeonim Shaarei Tzedek chelek 3 shaar 4 siman 20) cited by **the Ritz Geius** (Hil. Avel), the **Ramban** (Toras Haadam: Shaar Haavel; inyan hahaschala), **the Ran** (chiddushim to Moed Katan; dinei kvurah: aveilus uminhagim), and **the Tur** (YD 376) mentions a custom of washing ones hand after returning from a cemetery before entering ones house and says that it is unnecessary but appropriate/permissible if one has the minhag.
The Ritz Geius identifies this Gaon as **R. Platoi (פלטואי) Gaon**.

The **Machzor Vitry** (280) too rules that it is unnecessary.

**Hagahos Ashri** (Moed Katan 3:86) quotes the **Or Zarua** that some mourners wash their hands upon returning from a cemetery and that this is permissible but isn't mandatory.

The Rambam doesn't appear to quote it.

Comment: I don't have a source, but I was taught to wash my hands after leaving a cemetery if there was an open grave, i.e., for a funeral.  But just to visit, and there was no open graves, it was not necessary.  I was also taught if there was no water at the cemetery, it was ok to wait till you got home and washed your hands before entering your house.

Comment: Why it's not mentioned by the Rambam is quite interesting. Since he holds a cemetary is a place of tumah like that of a bathhouse or bathroom. I suppose it would depend on what he holds in those cases as well.

Comment: @Dennis as per your comment, if one didn't wash by the cemetery and plans on washing at home would he be allowed to study Torah?