# If a person stepped over a dead body (in a graveyard) unaware that there was a dead body there. What does one do?

Tags: death

I read somewhere that you can’t do this. Is there anything a person can do to purify themself.

Please provide sources.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Joshua. To prevent this question to be closed because it might be asking for a practical halachic advice, it is advisable to edit this question. You can ask if there are any sources that describes such and so etc... In this case, I would advise you to contact your local Rabbi.

Comment: @Shmuel edited.

Comment: Are you a kohen? I've never heard of this being an issue, besides that it is disrespectful. For a kohen, however, they are not allowed to become tamei meis (impure by a dead body).

Comment: @ezra I thought this applied to everyone. I guess I am wrong. I am not kohen

Comment: 1. Why does he have to purify himself if he doesn't legit know that there's a Corpse there.  How does he know. And besides, there has been no Parah Adumah to purify anyway.

Comment: 2. Follow the advice of a True Chakham who will tell him his practical advice.. "Tiberias had been built by Herod Antipas on a site where there were many tombs (Josephus, "Ant." xviii. 2, § 3), the exact locations of which had been lost. The town therefore had been regarded as unclean.

Comment: ... Resolving to remove the cause of the uncleanness, Simeon (Rashbi) planted lupines in all suspected places; wherever they did not take root he knew that a tomb was underneath. ... https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13723-simeon-ben-yohai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As, Ezra stated in the comments (I've not seen that until I published this answer), if you are a Kohen, then this does not apply to you, since a Kohen is not allowed to become impure through this.

The [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 199:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.199.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says:

> It is forbidden to step upon graves because some Poskim maintain that it is forbidden to derive benefit from them. However, if you have to visit a certain grave, and have no way of getting there unless you step upon other graves, it is permitted.

Regarding washing after leaving a cemetry, see [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57338/27180) answer.

The [Magen Avraham (4:20)](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.4.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that you can wash yourself (netilat yadayim) after visiting a cemetry because there are bad spirits (שדים)

> בין המתים. היינו בית הקברות (תשובת מהרי"ל סי' כ"ג) וכתב שיש ליטול קודם שיתפלל על הקברות ורוחצין שנית בשובו לחצר בה"ק שהשדים מלוין החוזרים ויש לרחוץ גם הפנים עכ"ל ע"ש:

See also: [Mishnah Berurah 4:42](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.4.42?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> and wash a second time upon returning to the courtyard of the cemetery, because evil spirits accompany those who leave. There are those who also wash their face at that time.